# SlideToggle() not working correctly on hover event (jQuery 1.4.1)

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, version, jquery-1.4

I am creating a new function for a navigation bar.  It used to drop down when you click on it but the new way is when they hover of the arrow (that points down).

The issue I'm having is the script I've written for this works great in newer version of jQuery but doesn't work correctly in the version this site has.

Please see example with the **latest version** of jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/titanium/wDEjs/

Please see example with **version 1.4.1**: http://jsfiddle.net/titanium/SmhHM/

There's nothing wrong with the script itself (for the newer one) but it needs to change so it worked in **version 1.4.1** to get round the error/bug in this version.  Even if someone knows what the error/bug is and could point me in the right direction to get round this, that would be great.

*I understand the best thing to do would be to use a newer version of jQuery but I have tried this and it seems to muck up a few things around the site (and it's a very large site).*

Here's the code I'm using at the moment (which works fine in the latest version of jQuery):

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li>Page <span>sub</span></li>
    <li>Page <span>sub</span></li>
    <li>Page <span>sub</span></li>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</ul>

<div class="sub">
    <p>Some stuff here for the menu</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
li {
    float:left;
    padding:0 50px;
    background-color:#eee;
}
span {
    cursor:pointer;
}
.clear {
    clear:both;
}
.sub {
    width:400px;
    height:300px;
    display:none;
    background-color:#ccc;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("span, .sub").hover(function() {
        $(".sub").stop(true, false).slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One work around in this situation (not a nice one but it works, especially when dealing with older versions of the jQuery library):

```
<script src="/js/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var jQuery_1_9_1 = $.noConflict(true);
</script>
```

When you call your jQuery function, rather than using the global variable `$` use the variable you have created. In this case that would be `jQuery_1_9_1`.

**The end result would be this change in the script:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("span, .sub").hover(function() {
        jQuery_1_9_1(".sub").stop(true, false).slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: That's not a very effective solution.

Comment: The problem with coding professionally is finding an effective solution within a certain amount of time. If you spend more time than you've quoted for a job, you loose money. If you don't make money on a job, you don't make a profit and can no longer pay the bills. So as far as an effective solution, it's a solution that sorts the problem. Got a better idea?

Answer (score -1):

don`t know really why its working like that, but it does work with jquery 1.4.1 and if you change the second parameter of the stop, to true, it`ll work, a little buggier but it`ll work, cause it`ll jump to the end of the animation, what happens if you leave that on false, is that if you don`t let the animation finish, it`ll then slide to the previous point where it ended.

Comment: No, the idea is to not have the queue jump to the end, but the first parameter clears the queue.  This is so the drop down doesn't disappear.  There is a clear fix in the later versions of jQuery, it has the same bug up to `1.6.4`. This doesn't answer my question.